# BOOL returning -1, 0 or positive

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, msdn

I'm a bit confused by the msdn GetMessage explanation.

They state that BOOL GetMessage() can return 0 when the method retrieves WM_QUIT. It returns -1 when there is an error and it returns positive for any other message.

But how can this be. A Boolean should be false or true, 0 or 1. How can it return a -1.

Link to msdn GetMessage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage

Comment: BOOL isn't really boolean like one would expect, you must keep in mind that one of Microsoft's directives is to keep users confused at all times :)

Comment: @anastaciu bool is a new feature in C++ (and also C), so obviously MS had no choice but to use an int for it. There's nothing confusing about it, since in C and C++ all non-zero values are true, and the same applies to `BOOL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows: How big is a BOOL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843134/windows-how-big-is-a-bool)

Comment: @phuclv and here I was thinking I had an opportunity to badmouth MS

Comment: [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Type BOOL is just a typedef of an integer. You must not confuse this with the cpp bool because it can only be true and false

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows world, `BOOL` is a type-alias for `int` (according to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)). Therefore it can have any value that an `int` could have.